# Multiple doOnError with retryWhen

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have the following observable Chain:

```
 public <T> Observable<T> request(Observable<T> request) {
        return request.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe(() -> {
                    errorView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                })
                .doOnError(throwable -> {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    errorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                })
                .doOnCompleted(() -> setVisibility(GONE))
                .retryWhen(o -> this.onClick());
    }
```

I pass my request Observable as parameter, as you can see I have a `doOnError` and `retryWhen` in the chain. What I want is to add another error handler in the request Observable (the parameter). I tried to subscribe to `doOnError` before it pass to the function and also `after` but neither of them worked.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here - do you want to add a second `doOnError`?

Comment: @DanielLew Exactly! And the second should be executed after the first one.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I tried to subscribe to doOnError before it pass to the function and also after but..."?

Comment: Then why not just put a second `doOnError()` after the first one? You can do it as many times as you want.

Comment: Do you mean you want the other `doOnError` "outside" of `request()`?

Comment: Yep! I want to have two subscribe to handle the error